# Two more topologies on unitary groups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, automorphism-groups

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and let $\operatorname{U}(H)$ be the group of unitary transformations of $H$. It is well known that the weak, strong and compact-open topologies on $\operatorname{U}(H)$ all agree ([Espinoza and Uribe - Topological properties of the unitary group](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1869)).

In particular, they all induce the standard topology on the center $\operatorname{U}(1) \subset \operatorname{U}(H)$, and the quotient $P{\operatorname{U}(H)} = \operatorname{U}(H)/{\operatorname{U}(1)}$ is a topological group.

Now, $P{\operatorname{U}(H)}$ is the automorphism group of the $C^*$-algebra $A = \operatorname{B}(H)$, and for generic $C^*$-algebras, one usually considers the "point-norm-topology" on the automorphism group $\operatorname{Aut}(A)$, which is just the restriction of the strong topology on space of all bounded operators on $A$.

On the other hand, since $\operatorname{B}(H)$ is a von Neumann algebra, the more natural topology may be Haagerup's *u-topology* (see [Haagerup - The standard form of von Neumann algebras](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24490737)). By Corollary 3.8 in Haagerup's paper, for $\operatorname{B}(H)$ this coincides with the *p-topology*, which is the restriction of the locally convex topology on the set of all $\sigma$-weakly bounded transformations of $A$ given by the collection of seminorms $$\varphi \mapsto \lvert\xi(\varphi(a))\rvert, ~~\xi \in A_* ,a \in A, \varphi \in \operatorname{Aut}(A).$$
Here $A_*$ denotes the predual, which in our case is the space of trace-class operators.

**Q: Do these two topologies on $P{\operatorname{U}(H)}$ also coincide, and are they equal to the quotient topology of the weak/strong topology?**

Comment: What is the locally convex topology on the space of all bounded operators?

Comment: Isn't it true that for a separable Hilbert space 
 the u-topology on U()
 and the weak topology coincide?

Comment: @Echo: Reworded the definition of the point-norm topology appropriately. Regarding, your second comment: This is precisely the question (or one of them). If you have an answer or a reference, it would be great if you could add that.

Comment: The $u$-topology is the "right" topology for $\mathrm{Aut}(M)$ for a von Neumann algebra $M$ (which is $B(H)$ in this case) and so it gives us the right topology on $P\mathrm{U}(H)$, which is the quotient SOT. The point-norm topology seems to give rise to a pathological topology, which is definitely not the quotient SOT nor norm.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA: Could you elaborate on why the point-norm topology does not coincide with the other two topologies, and what you mean by "pathological"?

Comment: (1) Take a suitable unitary operator $v$ on $K$ and put  $u_n :=1^{\oplus n}\oplus\bigoplus_{k>n} v$ on $H :=\bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty K$. Then $u_n\to1$ in SOT, but $\mathrm{Ad}\,u_n$ does not converges in point-norm. (2) For any $h=h^* \in Z(B(H)^{**})$, there is a norm-central net $h_j=h_j^* \in B(H)$ that converges to $h$ in $\sigma(B(H)^{**},B(H)^*)$ by Day--Namioka trick. The net $u_j := e^{\imath h_j}$ is norm-central but does not converges in quotient-norm. (3) It is pathological because it isn't familiar and some basic properties might be independent of ZFC (see arXiv:0808.3763).